# how to manage selecting many data from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 3 tables in my mysql database,
2 of them are with 10,000+ rows and the 3rd are with 100+ rows.

my query is

```
SELECT `deals`.`name`,
       `deals`.`id` as `deals_id`, 
       `reports`.`dealid`,
       `reports`.`pdeealnum`,
       `reports`.`pconfirmed`,
       `reports`.`pdate`,
       `reports`.`ppay`,
       `reports`.`pfname`,
       `reports`.`plname`,
       `reports`.`pmail`,
       `reports`.`paddress`,
       `reports`.`pphone`,
       `reports`.`pdate`,
       `orders`.`id` as `coupon`,
       `orders`.`dealid`
  FROM `deals`
LEFT JOIN `reports` ON `reports`.`dealid` = `deals`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`dealid` = `deals`.`id`
    WHERE `reports`.`pdate` >= '".strtotime($_POST['start_date'])."'
      AND `reports`.`pdate` <='".strtotime($_POST['end_date'])."'
 ORDER BY `reports`.`pdate` DESC
```

How can I manage selecting this much data without the site stuck or fail?

Comment: question makes little sense in its current form...

Comment: Yoni,  What type of reports are you trying to generate from this data?  This isn't a particularly large database, but doing a bunch of full table scans on all the tables is going to slow you down.

Comment: what those it mean indexed?
and i cant do limit because i need to export the data to EXCEL file.

Comment: @Brain Hoover i know i dont designed the DB.

Comment: Are you actually experiencing issues?

Comment: That could be a thousand and one things, do you know it is to do with the SQL query?

Comment: Does the query run manually? What are the tables structure (post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table(s)`? What are the indexes? Why is there no limit? Do you need these results live, or can you cache them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your dba adds the appropriate indexes to the pdate field.

Then, if you find you are experiencing performance issues, look into more advanced ways of improving performance. Things like paging in your application, partitioned tables, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To find out what indexes, if any, are being used in your report, run an [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) on your query.

You probably want indexes on

- deals.id (though I'm assuming it's the primary key already, and thus doesn't need another index)
- orders.dealid
- reports.dealid
- reports.pdate

Also, make sure that deals.id is the exact same data type as orders.dealid and reports.dealid (including NULL/NOT NULL and signed/unsigned).